# C++ switch always goes to default

Tags: c++

When I use `switch` it always prints the `default` value, regardless of the value entered. I included `break` after every `case` statement. How can I fix it?

```
// Lab 4 color.cpp
// This program lets the user select a primary color from a menu. 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int choice;    // Menu choice should be 1, 2, or 3

               // Display the menu of choices
cout << "Choose a primary color by entering its number. \n\n";
cout << "1 Red \n" << "2 Blue \n" << "3 Yellow \n";

// Get the user's choice
cin >> choice;

// Tell the user what he or she picked
switch (choice)
{
case '1': cout << "\nYou picked red.\n";
    break;
case '2': cout << "\nYou picked blue.\n";
    break;
case '3' : cout << "\nYou picked yellow.\n";
    break;
default: cout << "You entered an invalid option. Please run again and choose 1, 2, or 3.\n";
    break;
} 

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try removing the apostrophes surrounding the numbers in the `case` statements

Comment: You are confusing numbers with representations of numbers. The user is entering an integer like one (the number of heads I have) or two (the number of hands I have) and you are comparing it to a digit like `1` (a symbol that looks a lot like a straight line) or `2` (a symbol used in Arabic numbering to indicate the number two).

Comment: I strongly suggest developing a habit of logging the switch value (`choice` in your example) in the `default` case. You wouldn't need to ask this question if it just printed *what* the invalid option was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your select, your `case` is a character but you are selecting on an integer.

So change

```
case '1'
```

to

```
case 1
```

Alternatively change

```
int choice;
```

to

```
char choice;
```

etc.